# String connect in shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

What command can be used to connect some strings in shell script
For example,

```
./test.sh hello world ...
```

I want to convert it to

```
***hello***world***....
```

how to write the shell?

```
function strconnect() {
   for i in $@ {
      ... //how to write?
   }
}
```

I use bash on ubuntu system

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can concatenate strings using `""`:

```
function strconnect() {
   r=''
   for i in $@
   do
      r="${r}***${i}"
   done

   echo "${r}***"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `printf`:

```
strconnect() { printf "***"; printf "%s***" "$@"; }

str=$(strconnect hello world)

echo "$str"
***hello***world***
```

or this:

```
strconnect hello world you there; echo
***hello***world***you***there***
```